# how to git clone a SSH repo with multi user ssh keys present in .ssh folder

Tags: git, ssh

how to clone a repo which starts with ssh://something.git to machine

I'm on windows machine. 
I have multi ssh keys in .ssh folder.

how can i specify git to use particular ssh key and clone ssh:// url..?

Answer (score 0):

Use `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host git-host
  IdentityFile path/to/key
```

The underlying `ssh` will select that key given that the git repository is on `git-host` server (the part of `ssh://` URL).